see vdso function with perf report
On my perf report I see a bunch of lines with vdso modules and no function names. I am guessing these are for gettimeofday type calls. But how can I see actual function calls?
My perf record command:
sudo perf record -a -g -k 1 --call-graph dwarf,16384 -F 99 -e cpu-clock:pppH -p $PID -- sleep 60

and using sudo perf report to view the report. It shows something like:
+    2.83%     0.00%  myprog  [vdso]              [.] 0x00007fff983f6738

I am on kernel version 5.10 using Amazon Linux 2.

You need to have symbols available for the vDSO telling you the function names. However, vDSO symbols are not always included by default in the perf data. For many Linux distributions, you can install a package that contains such debug symbols.
sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg

